# LWC OSS Build Command

Tags: lwc-oss

I'm trying to build an LWC OSS project for production, but I can't figure out where the 'npm run build' command builds the bundled resource. I don't see anything obvious in the configs or on either of these sites

https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app/blob/main/packages/lwc-services/example/lwc-services.config.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwc/compiler

I'm using the default settings and I think it must be something here in the lwc-services.config.js

```
lwcCompilerOutput: {
    production: {
        compat: false,
        minify: true,
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: 'production'
        }
    }
}
```

can I specify a file name and location and what is the default file name and location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default directory is "dist", but you can change this. Find your `project.json` file, and locate this section:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "lwc-services build -m production",
```

And add the desired destination to the command:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "lwc-services build -m production -d prod",
```

Where `prod` is the desired output directory.

Depending on what you're doing, you may need to update additional scripts, as they presume that dist is the source for your production build.

Comment: cool thanks, I see two files in there app.js and 0.app.js do you know what the difference is?

Comment: @ScottMorrison 0.app.js  is the LWC runtime, app.js is your main app component's JavaScript. Both are necessary for LWC OSS to run.